# How to count product after using filter in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following line to show the total item:

```
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;

global $wp;
$current = home_url( $wp->request );
if ($current == 'https://example.com/product-category/mobile'){
    
$term = get_term( 55, 'product_cat' ); 
echo  $term->count; 
    
}
```

and it only counts the product in a specific category. But imagine visitor clicks on a few filters on `mobile` category (like brand, camera, and etc) then the result still counting the total product in that category, I searched for a solution to ***update the product count after using filters***, unfortunately, I couldn't find any way. Please share with me any solution that can help me.